# How To Easily Show A Diff Between Two Versions Of A Composer Package

Tags: composer-php, phpstorm, diff

Is there an easy way to show a diff between two different versions of one Composer package? Of course, I could manually or semi-automatically download the two versions and then manually run a diff on them. However, it would be quite handy to have a command like

```
composer diff namespace/module 1.0.0 1.0.1
```

This would show a diff between the versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 of package `namespace/module`, so that I can easily review what has changed.

Is there any smart way to do that?

It would even be nicer if I could see the diff in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in the project directory, JQ must be installed.

It installs both package versions in temp folders and compares them.

Usage: ./composer-diff.sh foo/bar 1.0.0 2.0.0

```
#!/bin/bash

PACKAGE=$1 # namespace/module
OLD=$2
NEW=$3

PROJECT=`pwd`

TMPBASE=/tmp/$$

mkdir -p $TMPBASE/$OLD
mkdir -p $TMPBASE/$NEW

jq '{repositories}' composer.json > $TMPBASE/$OLD/composer.json
jq '{repositories}' composer.json > $TMPBASE/$NEW/composer.json
cp auth.json $TMPBASE/$OLD
cp auth.json $TMPBASE/$NEW

cd $TMPBASE/$OLD
composer require $PACKAGE $OLD

cd $TMPBASE/$NEW
composer require $PACKAGE $NEW

set +x
diff -ur $TMPBASE/$OLD/vendor/$PACKAGE $TMPBASE/$NEW/vendor/$PACKAGE > $PROJECT/composer-package.diff
```

Now the resulting `composer-package.diff` file can be openend in any editor.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this while  documenting myself about the existence of such a command for my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62419188/3389585). A similar feature was suggested in the [Composer issue tracker](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4129) previously. The author of that proposal made it into a separate tool, available [here](https://github.com/sminnee/composer-diff) (looks old, working status unknown). I'm not sure it covers your exact case, tough.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [Composer plugin](https://packagist.org/packages/ion-bazan/composer-diff) I created to compare differences between 2 `composer.lock` versions which generates the diff links to GitHub/BitBucket.

Simply install it using Composer:

```
composer global require ion-bazan/composer-diff
```

After updating your packages, run:

```
composer diff -l
```

which prints a summary of package changes and provides clickable links to each package's diff:

[image: Example Composer Diff output]

You can experiment with different options and flags, as explained in [README](https://github.com/IonBazan/composer-diff).